# Typescript Module not defined at runtime

Tags: javascript, typescript

Why am I getting the error: `TSDummyProject is not defined` at runtime?

dbentities.d.ts:

```
declare module TSDummyProject.Models {
    export class Part {
        ID: number;
        PartName: string; 
        ...
    }
}
```

manager.ts:

```
/// <reference path="dbentities.d.ts"/>
class PartManagerController {
    private curPart: TSDummyProject.Models.Part;
    ...

    someFunction(){
        // error: TSDummyProject is not defined 
        this.curPart = new TSDummyProject.Models.Part(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you 'declare' something in typescript it does not generate any javascript. This is typescripts means of saying that "this is defined elsewhere e.g JavaScript code. Assume its there."

in your case it isn't. Perhaps you mean to write the code in typescript, or, forgot to include the aforementioned JavaScript in the page

Comment: And how to import javascript `export` in typescript? Simple including the js file not working